# How to use php array with sql

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I am creating an array list with AJAX. When I query SQL I get a missing list. Array's second element is not appearing in query.

**ajax.php**

```
require_once("connection.php");
$keywords = $_POST['keyword'];
$keywords = array_map("strtolower",$keywords);
$new_keyword= implode(",",$keywords );

$query = mysqli_query($connect,"select images.image_url,keyword.keyword from keyword inner join images on images.id = keyword.id where keyword.keyword in ('$new_keyword')");

$number= mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

output should be 1 but 2
because $keyword = ['hi','name'];

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you incorrectly join the tables "on images.id = keyword.id". I dont know your BD schema but I suspect it should be "on images.keyword_id = keyword.id" or "on images.id = keyword.image_id" or something similar. Give us an example data i those tables as well as table definitions.

EDIT: starting from the 4th line change the code to:

```
$new_keyword= implode("','",$keywords );
$new_keyword = "'".$new_keyword."'";

$query = mysqli_query($connect,"select images.image_url,keyword.keyword from keyword inner join images on images.id = keyword.id where keyword.keyword in (".$new_keyword.")");
$number= mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: images table       keyword table
id image_url        id keyword
both tablodas have the same id. I post a group of words with ajax.
" $keywords = $_POST['keyword']; " but only the first word is coming out in query.